# named pipe proxy over SSH

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, netcat, fifo

I am used to forwarding a remote service port on localhost using ssh like:

`ssh -L 2181:localhost:2182 user@server`
(forward remote host port 2182 to local port 2181)

now, from the machine I ssh to, I am trying to reach a tcp service and forward the response to my local machine:

`local-machine:2181 <-- SSH --> remote-machine:2182 <-- netcat/named pipe --> service:2181`

Note: I do not have direct access to the service machine, I only have access to the network through the machine I SSH to.

I was trying to use netcat with a named pipe:

On the remote-machine:

```
mkfifo fifo
nc -k -l 2182 <fifo | nc service 2181 >fifo
```

On local machine: 
`echo message | nc localhost 2181`

but that doesn't seem to work.

I also tried, on remote-machine
`nc -k -l 2182 0<fifo | nc service 2181 1>fifo`

without luck

On the remote machine `nc -k -l 2182` outputs the message I send from the local-machine:2181

if I simply pipe this like: `nc -k -l 2182 | nc service 2181` 
I do see the response from the service on the remote-machine. So I'm able to go all the way to the service and back to the remote-machine but it stops there:

`local-machine:2181 <-/- SSH --> remote-machine:2182 <-- netcat --> service:2181`

so I don't understand why the named pipe won't forward the response through the ssh connection back to my local machine.

`echo message | nc localhost 2182` on the remote-machine does NOT output anything back on the local-machine, so it's not making it through SSH for some reason.

Any idea why this is and how to fix it?

Thanks for help.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Are you tryint to do `ssh -L 2181:service:2182 user@server`?

Comment: I cannot SSH to `service` directly, but I can SSH to the remote-machine that has access to the service. This is running in containers and I don't want to have a SSHD server in every container. I have a SSHD container that then is part of the network. I need to SSH to it and then proxy to the other services.

Comment: I see... I tried and it works. I always thought the localhost in that -L string was the local machine, not the localhost of the remote machine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as pointed by @ysdx

the simple solution is:

`ssh -L 2181:service:2182 user@server`